# Как составить массив исходя из атрибута тега?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть теги:

```js
<a id= "0,0"  data = "1" >  </a>
<a id= "1,0"  data = "0" >  </a>
<a id= "0,1"  data = "1" >  </a>
<a id= "1,1"  data = "0" >  </a>
<a id= "2,1"  data = "3" >  </a>
<a id=" 0,2"  data = "2" >  </a>
<a id= "1,2"  data = "1" >  </a>
```

нужно взять из тега атрибут "id" (который содержит информацию для создания массива) . Первое число слева (перед запетой) это порядковый номер элемента в массиве. Второе число - это номер другого массива. Атрибут "data " содержит элемент который должен попасть в массив.

В итоге должно получиться :

```js
var general_massiv = [
  [1, 0],
  [1, 0, 3],
  [2, 1]
]
```

Можно ли это сделать стандартными средствами javascript или jquery ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
    function test() {
        var arr = [];
        function parse(a) {
            var id = a.getAttribute("id").split(",");
            var data = a.getAttribute("data");
            var i = id[1];
            if (arr[i] == null) arr[i] = [];
            arr[i][id[0]] = data;
        }
        var a = document.querySelectorAll("a[id][data]");
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) parse(a[i]);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
    }
    $(test);
</script>
```

Результат

```
[["1","0"],["1","0","3"],["2","1"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Конечно всё. Думаю, что будет проще через jQuery.

Сначала необходимо пробежаться по всем элементам с тегом "a" через $('a').each(...)

Следующим шагом необходимо взять атрибуты у этих элементов через $(this).attr(...)

Как только есть значения из атрибута "id", то можно разбить на массив по запятой через split.

Ну а потом уже добавлять все данные в Ваш массив.